# Trouble with hiding corner of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border, border-layout

I have a little trouble with my Jframe design.

I pictured my app with undecorated jframe, I want to hide the corners of the jframe at the top and bottom of window, but I don't know how to do it, please help me to solve this problem.

Image of frame :

[image]

Comment: Set background with alpha = 0.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi Please can you explain detailed

Comment: This tutorial will help you :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Comment: You just need to write myJFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color (0,0,0,0));

Comment: @Laurent-P not working ((

Comment: @Berger very useful tutorial, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a undecorated window like this.

```
 Container c = getContentPane();
 JPanel main = new JPanel();
 main.setOpaque(false); // This is very important.
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("signal.png"));
 main.add(new JLabel(icon));
 c.add(main);
```

Then set the frame undecorated property to false like this.(you might have done this)

```
 myframe.setUndecorated(true);
 myframe.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0)); // This is important.
 myframe.setVisible(true);
 myframe.pack();
 myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you Beniton, this works, thank you very much !

Comment: Glad it helped you.